# Get one result on sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Have a website with 2 tables (profile and photo). I want to get one profile with a photo, but I get many photos with same profile. I want just one.

```
SELECT ph.path as photo, pro.id_profile, pro.name, pro.address 
FROM profile pro, photo_profile ph 
WHERE pro.id_profile = 41 
AND pro.id_profile = ph.id_profile;
```

Please help me!

Comment: is this something like facebook profiles?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the `limit` clause of the select statement to limit the rows returned.

```
SELECT ph.path as photo, pro.id_profile, pro.name, pro.address 
FROM profile pro, photo_profile ph 
WHERE pro.id_profile = 41 
AND pro.id_profile = ph.id_profile
LIMIT 1;
```

Keep in mind that, without an `ORDER BY` clause, SQL won't guarantee *which* row you get.

As an example, say you have the following names in a table: `Allan`, `Barbara`, `Colin` and `Debbie`. The query:

```
select name from people limit 1;
```

will get you *one* row but an indeterminate one. On the other hand:

```
select name from people order by name asc limit 1;
```

will get you `Allan`.

Full syntax details for MySQL `select` can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html), including the `limit` clause.

Keep in mind that `limit` may not be in all database management systems (it *is* in MySQL, which is your specific case here). For example, DB2 uses `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `LIMIT` or `GROUP BY` depending on your needs, and using a proper `JOIN` will improve readability:

To get just the first result of your set, use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT ph.path as photo, pro.id_profile, pro.name, pro.address 
FROM profile pro
JOIN photo_profile ph ON 
WHERE pro.id_profile = 41 AND pro.id_profile = ph.id_profile 
LIMIT 1;
```

To group your results by the profile ID, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ph.path as photo, pro.id_profile, pro.name, pro.address 
FROM profile pro
JOIN photo_profile ph ON pro.id_profile = ph.id_profile
WHERE pro.id_profile = 41 
GROUP BY pro.id_profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why your database has more than one photo per profile you may want to debug from the results of this :-

```
SELECT * FROM profile pro, photo_profile ph WHERE pro.id_profile = ph.id_profile;
```

This is just a plain join of the profile and photo_profile tables.